# Função 'require' com outra função associada?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Num projeto simples de 'chat', o qual já usei e funciona 100%, usa-se

```
const express =require('express');//para http
const app = express();//instancia
const http = require ('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(http);
```

Eu já procurei uma resposta específica, mas ainda não encontrei o significado da aplicação desse objeto 'http' entre parênteses, em ('socket.io')(http).

Esses parênteses significam o quê? Significam um função anônima associada ao require?

Não entendi como isto funciona e, assim, quando usar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Isso é uma [high order function](https://medium.com/lfdev-blog/me-explica-96651fc2c105), basicamente é uma função que retorna uma função e executa a função retornada.

Como podemos ver no exemplo a seguir:

```js
function soma(a,b){
  return a+b;
}

function subtracao(a,b){
  return a-b;
}

function multiplicacao(a,b){
  return a*b;
}

function retornaAlgumaOperacao(op){
    switch(op){
      case '+': return soma;
      case '-': return subtracao;
      default: return multiplicacao
    }
}

console.log(retornaAlgumaOperacao('+')(1,1));
console.log(retornaAlgumaOperacao('-')(1,1));
console.log(retornaAlgumaOperacao('*')(1,1));
```

Perceba que a função `retornaAlgumaOperacao` não sabe qual operação ela retornará, mas sabe que será uma função que executará uma operação com dois parâmetros. Quando essa função é retornada, sabemos que temos que enviar dois parâmetros para executar a operação.

Isso aumenta a legibilidade para códigos que executariam funções encadeadas, por exemplo.

No caso específico do socket.io, o segundo parâmetro serve para ele retornar um [Server](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#new-Server-httpServer-options), em que o primeiro parâmetro diz onde o socket vai estar amarrado.

Comment: Muita boa explicação. Contudo, cada particularidade, cada exceção, confunde a gente, tal como na linha ... case '+': return soma; ... Aqui, a função 'soma' é provocada sem os parênteses e os argumentos necessários e, mesmo, assim ela dá conta do recado. É difícil acompanhar todos esses detalhes de sintaxe.

Comment: @MauroSimoes com o tempo a gente vai se acostumando com as nuances de cada linguagem, haha, mas, basicamente, quando você não coloca os parênteses no nome de uma função, o javascript entende que ele deve retornar a função como um todo. Da mesma forma que você pode atribuir uma função a um nome como `const minhaFunc = fuction() {}` e depois só chama pelo nome `minhaFunc` (:

Comment: você falou, tá falado. Quem sabe, sabe; quem não sabe, pergunta.

Answer (score 5):

> Esses parênteses significam o quê?

Esses são parenteses de chamada de uma função:

```
function func1(x){
    //codigo
}

func1(val); //chamar a função func1
//   ^---^---> parenteses de chamada de função
```

Ou seja quando você faz `require('socket.io')` obtém uma função de volta, e de seguida chama essa função passando o objeto `http` como parâmetro.

Consegue ver bem que obtem uma função se fizer `console.log(require('socket.io'));`, que lhe dá:

> `function Server(srv, opts){ … }`

Ou seja obtém a função `Server` como retorno deste ultimo `require`.
Depois chama de seguida essa função `Server` e passa objeto `http`, ficando na função como o parâmetro `srv`, o primeiro parâmetro.

Isso também podia ser feito em dois passos, guardando a função primeiro numa variável e depois chamando:

```
const funcaoServer = require('socket.io');
const io = funcaoServer(http);
```

Comment: e funcionaria a estrutura apontada passando uma variável, ou uma string, ao invés de função a outra função?

Comment: @MauroSimoes não sei se percebi a pergunta. Está a perguntar se podia passar outra coisa a função que não o http ?

Comment: Isac, é isto mesmo que perguntei.

Comment: @MauroSimoes Só vai funcionar com uma variável que tenho o conteúdo que a função `Server` espera no primeiro parâmetro (`srv`), que no caso tem de ser um objeto com determinados campos. Se passar qualquer outro tipo de coisa não vai funcionar corretamente. Se fizer `console.log(http)` consegue ver a estrutura exata do objeto passado à função.